# Reading numbers from a file to store in a two-dimensional array in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to read from a file that looks like this

> 1 1 756.00 
>   1 2 996.45
>   1 3 5159.14
>   1 4 710.21
>   1 5 10.00
>   2 1 1449.00
>   2 2 416.10
>   2 3 3119.48
>   2 4 2130.63
>   2 5 0.00
>   3 2 810.30
>   3 3 2219.63
>   3 4 1151.03
>   3 5 0.00
>   4 1 1071.00
>   4 3 1319.78
>   4 4 1861.24
>   4 5 0.00

And then storing the numbers into a two dimensional array. The file, however, is also about 478 lines. This because I'm supposed to keep storing the current value, plus the value being read in every time it iterates. I don't know how to approach this at all. I've tried doing this

```
 while(!feof(fp)) 
 {
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
       fgets(buffer, 100, fp);
       sscanf(buffer, "%d", &i);

       for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
       {
           fgets(buffer, 100, fp);
           sscanf(buffer, "%d", &j);

           for(k = 0.0; k != ' '; k++) 
           {
               fgets(buffer, 100, fp);
               sscanf(buffer, "%lf", &value);
               sales[i-1][j-1] +=value;
           }
       }
    }
 }

fclose(fp);
```

But I'm pretty sure this isn't even the correct way to go about it. I just need at least some guidance in the right direction, please.

Comment: First off, surely `sales[i-1][j-1]` is a mistake? Please clarify where all of those numbers are supposed to go. At the moment you are reading entire lines and only parsing their first number for each. (I also don't get what that `k` loop is supposed to do...)

Comment: using `sales[i-1][j-1]` is bad because it will become out-of-range when `i==0` or `j==0`.

Comment: Because I only have two dimensions, I didn't know what to do with the third number in the line (that's supposed to be stored into the value) so I created `k`. I also don't know how to parse the next number. The numbers are supposed to be stored `sales[first number from line][second number from line] = third number from line`

Comment: That looks more like a problem for an array of `struct`s. Don't use a hammer to drill a hole.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the first and second values are the indexes. If so then this may work.

```
while ( fgets(buffer, 100, fp)) {
    if ( ( sscanf(buffer, "%d%d%lf", &i, &j, &value)) == 3) {
        sales[i-1][j-1] =value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
while(scanf("%d %d %lf", &r, &c, &v) != EOF)
    sales[r-1][c-1] += v;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this answers the question?